# Ionic Post Request File Not Found

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a simple post request by running my app on an Android device (6.0.1). AFAIK there is no CORS problem when doing this but the console outputs this:

(apiurl is replacing the actual url for reasons, the actual url is an IP address)

```
POST file:///android_asset/www/apiurl net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I've added the cordova whitelist plugin and set my content security policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

This is my post request code:

```
$scope.powerPrompt = function() {
    var pwr = alert("Power On");
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'apiurl',
      data: "data to be sent",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response) {
      // handle success things
      alert("success");
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // handle error things
    })
```

Comment: When you put in the IP address, are you putting it as `http://apiurl`?

Comment: @AlexChance Nope, I'm using the actual ip address in single quotes without http

Comment: @AlexChance thank you so much! This worked!

Comment: Not sure if you are running this in an emulator or what, but you need to prefix http, otherwise it will try to access via local file system. I will post as answer, if you would kindly mark and accept, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @AlexChance will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to ensure you prefix your url with `http://` otherwise it will try to access the file system via `file://`, which is why you received the file not found error.

Ensure you are making your request in the format:

`http://<api url>:<ports if necessaray>/path/`

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative URL - this can't work because your index.html is loaded with a `file://` URL.

Put `http://<your host>:<port>/path/to/resource` as the url parameter and it should work as expected.

When running the app on Android platform, AFAIK there should not be much of a problem when using `http` as protocol. But you can expect problems on iOS. Depending on the type of app it might generally be a better idea to use SSL encrypted network traffic with your servers. If you don't have a SSL certificate, try [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).